# Having problems with mapping a JSON using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to map the following JSON:

```
[{"id":7346,"name":"The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild","cover":{"url":"//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/jk9el4ksl4c7qwaex2y5.jpg","cloudinary_id":"jk9el4ksl4c7qwaex2y5","width":2709,"height":3816}},{"id":2909,"name":"The Legend of Zelda: A Link Between Worlds","cover":{"url":"//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/r9ezsk5yhljc83dfjeqc.jpg","cloudinary_id":"r9ezsk5yhljc83dfjeqc","width":406,"height":362}}]
```

It looks like this:
[JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN8qx.png)

I had no problems with mapping it when I didn't need "cover" field (my domain class had only ID and name). Now, I'm having problems when I need it as well.

This is the line of code that I use to map my JSON as a String (like I said, it works fine if I only stick to id and name fields).

```
List<Suggestion> suggestions = mapper.readValue(requestString, new TypeReference<List<Suggestion>>(){});
```

My **Suggestion.java** class:

```
public class Suggestion {

private long id;
private String name;
private Cover cover;

public Suggestion(){
}

public Suggestion(long id, String name, Cover cover) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.cover = cover;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Cover getCover() {
    return cover;
}

}
```

My **Cover.java** class:

```
public class Cover {
    private String url;
    private String cloudinaryId;
    private Integer width;
    private Integer height;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getCloudinaryId() {
        return cloudinaryId;
    }

    public void setCloudinaryId(String cloudinaryId) {
        this.cloudinaryId = cloudinaryId;
    }

    public Integer getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(Integer width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public Integer getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(Integer height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

}
```

I've used http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to get this idea (additionalProperties are not necessary for sure) and I'm not sure why it doesn't work anymore.

So what might be the problem here?

Comment: what are your problems?

Comment: Try these two links. [Link-1](http://json2java.azurewebsites.net/), [Link-2](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/).

Comment: use @JsonProperty annotation in Suggestion.java and Cover.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's examine what causes the problem. If you run the code with classes you've provided you will get following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "cloudinary_id"

The JSON in your example is following:

```
[
  {
    "id": 7346,
    "name": "The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild",
    "cover": {
      "url": "//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/jk9el4ksl4c7qwaex2y5.jpg",
      "cloudinary_id": "jk9el4ksl4c7qwaex2y5",
      "width": 2709,
      "height": 3816
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2909,
    "name": "The Legend of Zelda: A Link Between Worlds",
    "cover": {
      "url": "//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/r9ezsk5yhljc83dfjeqc.jpg",
      "cloudinary_id": "r9ezsk5yhljc83dfjeqc",
      "width": 406,
      "height": 362
    }
  }
]
```

What you miss is specifying JSON to property field mapping with `@JsonProperty` annotation. Update your `Cover` class to:

```
public class Cover {

    private String url;
    @JsonProperty("cloudinary_id")
    private String cloudinaryId;
    private Integer width;
    private Integer height;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getCloudinaryId() {
        return cloudinaryId;
    }

    public void setCloudinaryId(String cloudinaryId) {
        this.cloudinaryId = cloudinaryId;
    }

    public Integer getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(Integer width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public Integer getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(Integer height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

When JSON field maps 1:1 to class field name you don't have to use this annotation. It is required when JSON uses different naming than your Java class.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. Good luck!

Comment: I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433294/design-pojo-for-nested-levels-of-a-field-and-extract-id-from-the-last-level) related to nested fields and I am confuse on how can I make nested level POJO and extract id from the last level of `parentCategory`? Wanted to see if you can help me out.